# Ubuntu 20.04 and Huawei Mobile Stick E3372

Tags: internet, 20.04, mobile-broadband, huawei

I am trying to use the HUAWEI 4G Usb-Dongle E3372 with Ubuntu 20.04 but the module doesn't seem to work.

```
ubuntu@yolo:~$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 12d1:14dc Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. E33372 LTE/UMTS/GSM HiLink Modem/Networkcard
```

Do you have any advice?

**Update:**

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 192.168.1.88  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
    inet6 fe80::dea6:32ff:fe66:502e  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether dc:a6:32:66:50:2e  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 1546  bytes 135451 (135.4 KB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 1  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 1058  bytes 166563 (166.5 KB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 143  bytes 11669 (11.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 143  bytes 11669 (11.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether dc:a6:32:66:50:2f  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of ifconfig ?

Comment: Sure! please see my update

Comment: It seems that your DHCP is working and also there are some sent and received packets . So what's the problem ? Have tried pining some IP like 8.8.8.8 ?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to say that I am connected through an ethernet cable while trying to use the the stick.

Comment: Have you tried unplugging the ethernet cable and then just plugging your stick ?

Comment: Yes, I can't connect to the internet

Comment: You could check the below: https://askubuntu.com/questions/757638/can-not-connect-huawei-e3372-modem-on-ubuntu-15-10-please-help

Comment: Thanks, I get `sudo usb_modeswitch -v 12d1 -p 1f01 -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.conf 
Look for target devices ...
 Found devices in target mode or class (1)
Look for default devices ...
 No devices in default mode found. Nothing to do. Bye!`

Comment: @George there was another answer which explained a logical process to make it work. Unfortunately, it was using setting network configurations using the interfaces file. Trying to get the same result using netplan.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you plug the usb Dongle in and you get a steady blue led, issue:

```
ip link
5: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:aa:bb:cc:dd:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

you should get an eth1 as physical device.

If you are using network manager to handle connections, create an ethernet connection using eth1 and bring it up

```
sudo nmcli connection add type ethernet con-name huawei ifname eth1
sudo nmcli c up huawei
```